# Forcing SVG Images to Redraw on Demand

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

We have a web application with a navigation panel on the left, and an embedded Logi reports iframe on the right. The embedded reports use AJAX-based techniques and contain SVG elements.  The SVG elements are buried many layers deep within the DOM tree of the report (i.e. tables within tables, etc.).

The navigation panel can collapse by selecting a button control.  When it collapses, the SVG images are redrawn wider in the embedded report as the iframe expands. This is okay. But when we expand the the navigation panel back to the way it was, the SVG images don't change, the iframe width stays the same, and a horizontal scrollbar appears. We believe that the SVG images are not resizing, and are keeping the iframe from collapsing.

Using javascript, is there a way we can force the SVG images to redraw when the button is selected to expand the navigation panel, so that they will properly fill their resized container?

Comment: You shouldn't have to force anything. Does this happen on more than one UA?

Comment: Would you want to use a canvas context to manually redraw your SVG graphics?

Comment: Sorry - it happens to be a know issue with the particular version we are using of our reports application.  You are right - no need to force anything.